# Convert format full name pattern String

Tags: java, string, pattern-matching

I have a String "adam levine". How to convert first letter of every word to uppercase like this "Adam Levine"?

```
String line = "adam levine";
line = line.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + line.substring(1);
System.out.println(line); // Adam levine
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static final Pattern bound = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\w)");

public static String titleize(final String input) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(input.length());
    Matcher mat = bound.matcher(input);
    while (mat.find()) {
        mat.appendReplacement(sb, mat.group().toUpperCase());
    }
    mat.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: it's work good. can you explain more about "\\b(\\w)"?

Comment: \\w represent a word and \\b represent a word boundary